# Is there a phrase for or meaning to a function that is its own composite?

Tags: functions

If there is a function such that $$ f(f(x))=f(x) $$ and $$ f(f(f(x)))=f(x) $$ and so one and so forth for all composites, is there a specific name for that? It's not an involution because it's not it's own inverse, but I figured there must be some term for it.

Comment: $f(f(x))=f(x)$ implies $f(f(f(x)))=f(x)$ and so on.

Comment: Such property is called idempotence: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence

Comment: You can call the map idempotent.

Comment: An element such that x*x = x is called an idempotent element (for the operation *). So under compsition, $f$ is idempotent.

Comment: Also useful to know, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an *idempotent* function. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Unary_operation):

> A unary operation $f$, that is, a map from some set $S$ into itself, is called idempotent if, for all $x$ in $S$, $\;f(f(x))=f(x)\,$.

It follows by definition that an idempotent function satisfies $f(f(f(x)))=f(x)\,$, and by induction $f(f(\cdots f(x)\cdots)) = f(x)\,$.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the word idempotent.